# Check if member password is blank

Tags: cartthrob, members, profile-edit, password

Is it possible to conditionally show a form field if the member password field is blank. Something along the lines of

```
{if password == ""}SHOW THESE FIELDS{/if}
```

I have a Cartthrob shopping cart that auto registers member on purchase and I want to give them the opportunity of setting a password on the cart summary page. I don't want to show the set password form if they are a returning customer/member (ie password field is not blank)

Running 
EE 2.7.2
CT 2.5
PE

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something if they're a member and logged in you could use the conditional `if logged_in` to show/hide stuff or alternatively the opposite conditional `if logged_out` to show/hide stuff as well.

Also I'm not sure you can create a member without a password.

Comment: Thanks for your input Stewart. Cartthrob has a create user function as part of the checkout process. It must issue the user with a password if there is none provided in the checkout process.... so I'm heading down the wrong track here. I want the user to be able to checkout as a guest and register their details after checkout if they want.